# How to use context api with react-router-dom": "^5.2.0" and react": "^17.0.2"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-context

I'm trying to accessing the user value from my Header component using the Context API, but It gives me undefined.
Here is my code.

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const DashboardContext = createContext();

const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const userInitialState = localStorage.getItem("user") || "";

  const [user, setUser] = useState(userInitialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", user);
  }, [user]);

  const values = {
    user,
    setUser
  };

  return (
    <DashboardContext.Provider value={values}>
      {children}
    </DashboardContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AppContextProvider;
```

In The App Component:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import AppContextProvider from "./contexts/AppContext";
import Products from "./views/Products";
import Orders from "./views/Orders";
    <AppContextProvider>
       <Router>
         <Header />
         <Switch>
                <Route path="/products">
                  <Products />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/orders">
                  <Orders/>
                </Route>
              </Switch>
    </AppContextProvider>
```

THE HEADER COMPONENT:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import AppContextProvider from "../contexts/AppContextProvider";
import "../styles/Header.css";

const Header = () => {
  const context = useContext(AppContextProvider);
  console.log(context); // gives me undefined
return (
    <div className="row border-bottom text-white">
{user}
</div>
};

export default Header;
```

Inside of Header component i try to access to the user value but it gives me undefined
How can i resolve this because i'm new to react.
Please Help.
.................................................................................

Comment: Can you include your Header component?

Comment: i edited the question, adding the Header component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting undefined in your Header component is because you are using the wrong variable to access the Context.

You need to use the actual context value, rather than the Provider you set up. You need to use `const context = useContext(DashboardContext)` instead, and it will work.

```js
const { createContext, useEffect, useState, useContext } = React;

const DashboardContext = createContext();

const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const userInitialState = "You" || "";

  const [user, setUser] = useState(userInitialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`store: "${user}" to localstorage`);
  }, [user]);

  const values = {
    user,
    setUser,
  };

  return (
    <DashboardContext.Provider value={values}>
      {children}
    </DashboardContext.Provider>
  );
};

const Header = () => {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(DashboardContext);
  const changeUserName = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.target);
    setUser(data.get("user"));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Welcome {user}!</div>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={changeUserName}>
          <input name="user" />
          <button type="submit">Update Name</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <AppContextProvider>
    <Header />
  </AppContextProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```